# How to improve extraction of CSV columns in a loop

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm doing a script that extracts data from a CSV, and then sends it to an API.

So I have a class.

```
class Output <
    Struct.new(:sid, :pid, :rut, :name, :surname)
end
```

And then, the script does the extraction of columns from the CSV

```
file.each_line("\n") do |row|
        data = row.split(";")
        c = Output.new

        for i in 0..$.
            if data[i] == ''
                data[i] = 'Sin datos'
            end
        end

        c.sid = data[0]
        c.pid = data[1]
        c.rut = data[2]
        c.name = data[3]
        c.surname = data[4]
end
```

And it works. But my question is if there's a way to do this more efficiently.

I'm kinda new to ruby, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Struct` subclass constructor accept positional argument:

```
c = Output.new(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4])
```

And above expression can be expressed more shortly with splat operator (`*`):

```
c = Output.new(*data)
```

---

With [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
file.each_line do |row|
  data = row.split(";").map { |x| x == '' ? 'Sin datos' : x }
  c = Output.new(*data)
end
```

Comment: Fantastic, but how can I link, e.g., the `c.surname` with `data[4]`, as seen in my question?

Comment: @ignaces, As I shown in the answer, `c = Output.new(*data)`. You can also assign afterward as you did if you want: `c.surname = data[4]`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **Array#collect** to perform achieve same functionality.

```
file.each_line do |row|  
    data = row.split(";").collect { |x| x == '' ? 'Sin datos' : x }  
    c = Output.new(*data)  
end
```